# jquery ready function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, document-ready

I have some javascript placed inside of the jquery $(document).ready function.  It searches for an anchor in the url, and then runs a separate function to display matching content.

The code executes if I place an alert inside of the if statement somewhere, but wont' run otherwise.  I've stored all the anchor names in an array called 'anchorNameList', and am checking to see if the anchor in the URL exists.

I only want the function to run on the initial pageload, so I set the default value of 'currentAnchor' to 1000 and change it on each iteration.

```
        if (currentAnchor == 1000 && document.location.hash.substring(1)) {
        var checkForThisAnchor = document.location.hash.substring(1);
        for (var j=0; j < anchorNameList.length; j++) {
            if (anchorNameList[j] == checkForThisAnchor) {
                expandMe(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if it is working when you place alert means, there is some timing issue.

Comment: Is your jQuery script tag before or after your own JS file script tag? It needs to come before.

Comment: The jQuery script is called in the header. The expandMe function I'm calling is defined above the ready function.  Essentially, the order on the page is: head->(jQuery reference) body->(expandMe function, $(document).ready and included content).  Should I rearrange the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the onload event from jQuery's document.ready to window.ready.  It worked properly about 30% of the time, so it was definitely a timing issue.  It seemed the main JavaScript function on the page, which is retrieving list items, was running slowly.  I just moved this entire expanding function to the end of that list retrieval function, so it just runs linearly.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when a JavaScript problem magically fixes itself by adding an innocuous alert() somewhere, the source of the problem is typically an asynchronous request.

Under non-alert circumstances the async request hasn't finished yet.  But by adding the alert, it has a chance to finish, and therefore allowing your code to travel a different code-path than it would have hit without the response of the complete asynchronous call.